# AJAX handler not called (not sure if PHP or JavaScript issue)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, curl

I'm pretty stumped as to where I'm going wrong here. I'm making an AJAX call to a PHP file that takes XML, then generates a result based on that XML and echoes it. The AJAX handler is not called, though. Below is the JavaScript and PHP.

Thanks

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $.post("http://thedomain.co.uk/sendxml.php", { xmlData: '

      <thisiswhere>
        <myxmlis>
        </myxmlis>
      </thisiswhere>

    ' }, function(data) {alert(data)}, "xml");
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  $xml_builder = $_POST['xmlData'];

  // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
  $ch = curl_init('http://user:pass@myserver.com/api');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_builder);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo json_encode(htmlentities($ch_result));
?>
```

Comment: Your string syntax is not valid. Try linting your code at http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: strings aren't multiline in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing back JSON from the PHP script :

```
$(function() {
    var xml = '<thisiswhere><myxmlis></myxmlis></thisiswhere>';

    $.post("http://thedomain.co.uk/sendxml.php", { xmlData: xml }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

This implies that you're posting to the same domain.

Comment: Thanks very much! Will select as best answer when timer is up :)